# What does a colon in URL mean?

Tags: url

I've seen this image URL today and I'm wondering what is this `":small"` at the end.
Is this something related to the CMS used by Twitter? Or can this be used with any image URL?

```
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B9GOfXNIIAAxb0H.jpg:small
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's something that twitter parses; it's not standardized.

Answer (score 5):

colon ":" is not a special character in the url encoded strings, so the :small is part of the requested file name. The server side code use these flags in this case to be able serve the images in different size.

Answer (score 4):

Generally in cases like this

```
scheme://host.domain:port/path/filename
```

colon is used to specify port. But, in your case it is totally application specific. Generally does not mean anything.

Comment: It isn't 'used to specify the port'. It's just a separator. It doesn't 'mean' or 'specify' anything. In your own example it is also used to separate the scheme from the hostname.

Comment: So are all the "/"s. It's just a special separator that is generally used when we want to specify port. In short "used to specify port". And yes it also separates the hostname. But, there are cases when we do not need to specify ports.

Comment: @HossainMuctadir that's **not** the same. The http scheme specifies that it's `http://A[:B][/C]`, where **only** C is up to interpretation by the target server, A and B being used to connect to that.